# Balancing Data for Multiple-Instance Learning with Unbalanced Classes

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

### Balancing Data for Multiple-Instance Learning with Unbalanced Classes

**Problem Statement (Simplified):**

I have a CSV file where each row is labeled as either class A or B. Class A has 906 instances, while class B has 255 instances. I want to use this Multiple-instance Learning (MIL) classifier https://github.com/garydoranjr/misvm for classification. But apparently the data is very imbalanced.

**Additional Details:**

I'm conducting an analysis on time-series patterns of specific activities, particularly brain activities. Each row in the CSV file represents a 5-second window for a single instance. The total duration of the experiment is 'n' seconds, resulting in approximately 'n/5' 5-second windows with a 1-second shift between them (ignore if unfamiliar with this concept). Therefore, the total number of rows in the CSV file is roughly calculated as:

Total Rows = 906 * (n/5) + 255 * (n/5)

**Question:**

I'm considering duplicating rows of class B a certain number of times (e.g., 3 times) to balance the dataset. Is this a valid approach? Please also tell me if there are other approaches to tickle this kinda problem? Thanks in advance!